# I Have A Problem in Selecting Data From MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have problem in selecting the data from mysql database. I don't know how to explain my problem, so
here is the data I have in my `user` table...

> select * from user

```
USERID      NAME
.1.         A
.1.1.       B
.1.2.       C
.1.2.1.     D
.2.         E
.2.1.       F
.2.1.1.     G
.2.1.1.1.   H
.3.         I
.3.1.       J
```

The result I wish

```
PARENT  USERID      NAME
-       .1.         A
.1.     .1.1.       B
.1.     .1.2.       C
.1.2.   .1.2.1.     D
-       .2.         E
.2.     .2.1.       F
.2.1.   .2.1.1.     G
.2.1.1. .2.1.1.1.   H
-       .3.         I
.3.     .3.1.       J
```

Is that possible?

Comment: In which table parent name exist

Comment: yes first say do parent row exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking if the `USERID` matches the pattern of a `.` followed by some digits followed by a `.` as the entire string (using the regex `'^\\.[0-9]+\\.$'`) and if so, returning a `-`; if not, generating the substring of `USERID` up to (and including the second-to-last `.`):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN USERID REGEXP '^\\.[0-9]+\\.$' THEN '-'
         ELSE SUBSTRING(USERID, 1, LENGTH(USERID) - LOCATE('.', SUBSTRING(REVERSE(USERID), 2)))
    END AS PARENT,
    USERID,
    NAME
FROM user
```

Output:

```
PARENT      USERID      NAME
-           .1.         A
.1.         .1.1.       B
.1.         .1.2.       C
.1.2.       .1.2.1.     D
-           .2.         E
.2.         .2.1.       F
.2.1.       .2.1.1.     G
.2.1.1.     .2.1.1.1.   H
-           .3.         I
.3.         .3.1.       J
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v7VF6JQ4jhJsLk6brT4HxJ/0)

To also get the `NAME` of the `PARENT`, we `LEFT JOIN` the above result back to the `user` table on the `PARENT` value:

```
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(p.NAME, '-') AS PARENTNAME
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN USERID REGEXP '^\\.[0-9]+\\.$' THEN '-'
             ELSE SUBSTRING(USERID, 1, LENGTH(USERID) - LOCATE('.', SUBSTRING(REVERSE(USERID), 2)))
        END AS PARENT,
        USERID,
        NAME
    FROM user
    ) u
LEFT JOIN user p ON p.USERID = u.PARENT
ORDER BY USERID
```

Output

```
PARENT      USERID      NAME    PARENTNAME
-           .1.         A       -
.1.         .1.1.       B       A
.1.         .1.2.       C       A
.1.2.       .1.2.1.     D       C
-           .2.         E       -
.2.         .2.1.       F       E
.2.1.       .2.1.1.     G       F
.2.1.1.     .2.1.1.1.   H       G
-           .3.         I       -
.3.         .3.1.       J       I
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v7VF6JQ4jhJsLk6brT4HxJ/1)

Comment: Thank youu so much

Comment: Could u please help me on one thing more? How to get the name of the parent based on their userid? So if the parent got `.1.` then it should be `A`, if `.1.2.` then `C`, and so on

Comment: @VanesticaIreline that's probably worthy of another question, but I've edited my answer with how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can trim the characters between last 2 periods using substring_index

so your query will be something like below

```
select 
case when parent ='' then '-' else concat(parent,'.') end  as parent ,
userid,
name
from
(
select 
TRIM(TRAILING concat('.',substring_index(TRIM(TRAILING '.' from USERID), '.', -1),'.')  from USERID) as parent, 
NAME as name,
USERID from user
)tmp
```

working fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36435a/13

Comment: @Nick : nice catch mate , I fixed it and updated my answer. Thanks :)